# How to pass POST data using apache benchmark in node js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, benchmarking, apachebench

I am calling API built-in node js and passing the body with the POST method as JSON.
The JSON file contains the parameters as file `wallet_view.json`

```
{"version":4.2,"auth_token":"0625d8042e2b2a04c5770f54a0c7a83d","page":1}
```

and the index file of node js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const process = require('process');
const config = require('./config/config.js');

app.use(express.raw());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
    console.log('Uncaught Exception: ' + error);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(req.body);
    const routes_handler = require('./routes/index.js')(app, express, req);
    next();
});

app.listen(config.SERVER.PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running at Port " + config.SERVER.PORT);
});
```

The command which I am using is as follows:

```
ab -n 2 -c 1 -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -p ./wallet_view.json -A "username:password" -v 4 http://domainname.com/wallet/view
```

But, now in console log of `req.body`, I am getting the output as

```
{ '"version":4.2,"auth_token":"0625d8042e2b2a04c5770f54a0c7a83d","page":1': '' }
```

which is the wrong JSON format. This way I am unable to get `req.body.auth_token`. Can anyone please suggest what kind of modifications should I do in ab command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, It was the issue in the request format which I was passing. 
I was passing the request as `JSON`

```
{"version":4.2,"auth_token":"0625d8042e2b2a04c5770f54a0c7a83d","page":1}
```

As the API request will always come as form-urlencoded and in Node.js file, I am using `express.raw()`

```
app.use(express.raw());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

so it was the wrong format.
As I am using content-type as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.

So I should use the request format as

```
version=4.2&auth_token=0625d8042e2b2a04c5770f54a0c7a83d&page=1
```

This way I handled the problem. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

content type should be  `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

try like this,

```
ab -n 2 -c 1 -T 'application/json' -p ./wallet_view.json -A "username:password" -v 4 http://domainname.com/wallet/view
```

Comment: first thing, the API request will always come as form-urlencoded. that is why I have used app.use(express.raw());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
second, If i change as per your suggestion then in req.body I am getting {} blank